# Почему не устанавливается сфинкс 3.0.3?

Tags: ubuntu, битрикс, sphinx

У меня был сфинкс 2.2.9 на убунту16 , вследствие чего не заполнялись таблицы в битрикс. 
https://hsto.org/webt/5b/e7/b2/5be7b2edede36832166100.jpeg
что очень плохо, даже таблица `b_search_title` не заполнялась.
удалила так 2.2.9

```
apt-get remove sphinx
```

Решила установить 3.0.3

1. скачала архив с сайта `sphinxsearch`
2. распаковала архив
3. смотрю папку /bin/ этого архива и копирую в /var/bin/
4. `indexer --all --rotate -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf`
5. `searchd -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf`

вылезает ошибка:

```
WARNING: both 'sphinxdata' and config file '/home/user/sphinxdata/sphinx.conf' exist; using 'sphinxdata' folder
no config file, using 'sphinxdata' folder...
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
WARNING: No extra index definitions found in data folder
```

проделываю , не работает:

Завершаем демона цивилизованно, результат не важен:

```
searchd --stop
```

Убиваем всё цивилизованно не завершённое, результат не важен:

```
killall searchd
```

Мешают файлы sphinx.state и sphinx.state.new:

```
rm -f ~/sphinxdata/sphinx.state*

searchd -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf
```

те же самые ошибки.
потом меняю
конфиг добавила в ~/sphinxdata/ , подправила пути в нем, и опять делаю...

Завершаем демона цивилизованно, результат не важен

```
searchd --stop
```

Уубиваем всё цивилизованно не завершённое, результат не важен

```
killall searchd
```

Мешают файлы sphinx.state и sphinx.state.new:

```
rm -f ~/sphinxdata/sphinx.state*
searchd -c ~/sphinxdata/sphinx.conf
```

и странно, что тоже самое получается, запускаются два процесса для одной папки.... Эх....

```
user  2551  0.0  0.0  24008   320 ?        S    07:08   0:00 /usr/bin/searchd -c /home/taskgood/sphinxdata/sphinx.conf
user  2552  1.9  0.0  91748  3020 ?        Sl   07:08   0:20 /usr/bin/searchd -c /home/taskgood/sphinxdata/sphinx.conf
user  3250  0.0  0.0  21316  1084 pts/1    S+   07:25   0:00 grep --color=auto searchd
```

Даже все файлы предыдущей версии удалила - не помогло(те, что описаны вконфиге для sphinxsearch2.2.9 по пути etc)
и проделывала:

```
aptitude remove sphinx
aptitude purge sphinx
```

все равно такая ошибка:

```
WARNING: both 'sphinxdata' and config file '/home/user/sphinxdata/sphinx.conf' exist; using 'sphinxdata' folder
no config file, using 'sphinxdata' folder...
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
WARNING: No extra index definitions found in data folder
```

удалила папки и файлы...
проделала

```
aptitude remove sphinx
aptitude purge sphinx
```

опять повторила сначала, та же самая ошибка...
ребутнула несколько раз.
Помогите народ, с чем это связано, ума не приложу...

Comment: А когда `/var/bin` появился в убунте и стал частью `$PATH`?

Comment: "скачала архив с сайта sphinxsearch".

Очень. ОЧЕНЬ плохо. Не надо тащить в linux философию винды. Ничем хорошим это не заканчивается. Есть пакет `sphinxsearch`, используй его.

Comment: Я этой штукой не пользовался, но меня очень смущают пути начинающиеся на `/home/user`. Вот прям так оно и должно быть? Обычно настройки хранятся в `/etc`.

Comment: По поводу "таблица b_search_title не заполнялась. удалила так 2.2.9". А на чистой системе развернуть всё то же самое - всё равно не будет заполняться?

Comment: @donRumata, я ошиблась, путь /usr/bin

Comment: По поводу "таблица b_search_title не заполнялась. удалила так 2.2.9". А на чистой системе развернуть всё то же самое - всё равно не будет заполняться?
вот это идея...

Comment: Действительно, все настройки хранятся в /etc/

Comment: Действительно, все настройки хранятся в `/etc/`, но как я не прописывала
`searchd -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf` , все равно создается папка в текущей директории `sphinxdata` , прописала в текущую папку sphinxdata, все равно не помогло...
создаются два процесса на одну ти ту же папку ... при запуске `searchd`, что очень смешно...

Comment: А где почитать как разворачивать всю эту хрень? Я если время выкрою - попробую поковырять у себя в виртуалке.

Comment: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/sphinx3.html#getting-started-on-linux-and-macos
@donRumata, вот ссылка

Comment: Прочти мой второй комент.

Comment: @donRumata,  Спасибо за внимание, то есть бинарники по вашему , это плохо.... А чем они плохи, можно поинтересоваться?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416 - если вопрос не закроют, то народ и я накидаем best practice. Если закроют - отпишусь в следующем каменте

Comment: Вроде пока не закрыли, даже кто-то в избранное утащил. Так что го туда.

Comment: Ну чё, починила?

Comment: ТС, проблема решена? Если да, то ответьте на свой вопрос, если не сложно. По теме: `apt-get remove sphinx` удаляет пакет, НО оставляет конфиги. И новая версия на это ругается. Используйте `apt-get purge sphinx`, и на всякий - посмотрите, удален `/etc/sphinx` или нет.

Comment: Спасибо, ребята за помощь огромное!
я установила сфинкс 2.2.11 . по совету donRumanta.
С наступающим Новым годом, дорогие ребята!