# Почему ставить программы в обход пакетного менеджера linux плохо?

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, faq, deb

Не холивара ради, но накоплений точек зрения для.

Замучился отвечать одно и тоже в одинаковых темах "я запустил .run и всё сломалось", "я распаковал tar и компьютер взорвался", поэтому создал вопрос, чтобы в дальнейшем ссылаться сюда.

Comment: Напишите сами ответ на свой вопрос, вы же его знаете. Тогда от вопроса будет польза

Comment: Я написал и пошёл спать. И щас тоже иду. Утром встану и напишу, неделя была адской. Написал, чтобы не забыть это сделать.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, накидал на скорую руку, что лежит прям на поверхности.

Comment: плюсанул вопрос и ответ)

Comment: @KAGGDesign, есть кстати чё добавить? Я уже раз пятый вычитываю текст.

Comment: Да не, все ок. Мог бы, ещё раз плюсанул) Думаю, что вопрос достаточно хорошо освещён, а делать из него энциклопедию, пожалуй, не стоит. Лучшее - враг хорошего)

Answer (score 13):

### Чем плохо:

1. **Плохое обновление**. В классическом варианте, менеджер пакетов сам проверяет наличие обновления, сам выкачивает и сам ставит. Руками поставленный бинарник или не будет обновляться вообще или будет обновляться тем способом, который выбрал разработчик. В итоге получаем кучу кастомных обновлялок, которые "висят в трее" и непонятно что делают.
2. **Плохое сопровождение**. Вытекает из первого пункта. Раз непонятно как программа обновляется (не факт, что через скрипт, может и через бинарник), то непонятно куда, что, как, когда, зачем она ставит. При передаче системы в другие руки - нужно больше документации и объяснений кто с кем дружит, а кого в сеть не пускаем.
3. **Зоопарк версий**. В linux библиотеки общие для всей системы. `QT`, `mp3`, `java` ставятся один раз и используются всеми, кому надо. В случае с ручной установкой, в систему (`/opt` тоже система) ставятся компоненты мутных версий, которые используются только этой программой. Проблемы начинаются, когда [надо](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=52945) [закрыть](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=55396) уязвимость, а что делать непонятно, потому что неизвестны (или надо сильно копать) версии и что сломается, если заменить один компонент, но оставить другой. Этим как раз и должен заниматься менеджер пакетов.
4. **Проблемы с совместимостью**. В системе может быть старая версия ядра или libc и тогда программа будет вести себя весьма странно, если вообще заведётся. Обновление libc руками может уронить вообще всё остальное.
5. **Большие затраты по силам и времени**. На большом количестве софта установленного руками, времени на поддержание версий в актуальном состоянии тратится просто вагон, а при наличии не одной машины - увеличивается до неприличных цифр.
6. **Проблемы с удалением**. При удалении проги надо удалить все бинарники, библиотеки, кэши и конфиги, пройтись по всем `/var/`, `/lib/` и `/usr/`. Самое главное - не удалить ничего лишнего, иначе см. выше про libc. На это тоже уходит порядочное количество времени.

### Чем хорошо:

1. **Свежие версии от разрабов**. Не надо дожидаться слоупоков от дистрибутива, которые будут тестировать никому ненужную совместимость с остальными компонентами.
2. **Не надо привыкать к другой философии**. На винде работало - чем тут хуже?
3. **Критические обновления безопасности ставят автоматом только трусы**. Меня это не коснётся, мой проект хакерам не интересен.
4. **Можно почувствовать себя Ъ-][@k3r0m** делая `./configure && make && make install` и превращая Ubuntu\CentOS\SuSe в Slackware.
5. **Можно прочувствовать всю боль мейнтейнеров** постоянно борясь с вылазиющими конфликтами компонентов.

### Дополнение 1.

Отдельно стоит упомянуть виртуалки и контейнеры. Хостовая система будет изолирована, внутрь их можно делать сколь угодно ужасный деплой (но помнить, что плохой код\конфиг в любом уровне абстракции остаётся плохим), если придерживаться концепции атомарного обновления: хочешь обновить что-то - обнови в новом окружении всё что надо, замени старое, а старое грохни.

### Дополнение 2.

Даже до Майков [дошло](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=53022), что менеджер пакетов это хорошо не только [для разработчиков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet).

### FAQ.

**Q:** А я делаю `make install` на локалхосте 5 лет и брат пока что жив.

**A:** Молодец, возьми пирожок с полки. deb\rpm\etc придумали не потому, что дело было вечером и делать было нечего. Древние задолбались ставить всё руками и решили ввести абстракцию для облегчения жизни себе и другим. Значит у тебя не те объёмы, чтобы понять какой подарок сделала концепция пакетных менеджеров для администрирования систем.

**Q:** Этим вашим `deb` и `dnf` я не могу поставить 2-3-5 версий библиотек в одну систему. Я буду продолжать использовать `tar xvf`.

**A:** Никто не Вуди Аллен^W^W идеален. Или иди в ногу со всеми и пиши на том, на чём сидит большинство или используй контейнеры\виртуалки. Как вариант - найди дистрибутив, в котором пакетный менеджер позволяет это делать.

**Q:** Тут нет самой свежей версии $AWESOME_SOFTWARE. Где там мой wget?

**A:** Пакетный менеджер $DISTRONAME не серебряная пуля, но он покрывает ~90% потребностей обычного пользователя или админа. Нужна свежая версия? Сами разрабы часто держат свою репу под популярные дистрибутивы. И там можно даже dev-ветку из гита попробовать. Чешутся руки **СОБИРАТЬ@КОМПИЛЯТЬ** - запакеть то, что собрал и после этого устанавливай. Так, менеджер пакетов будет знать что делать и куда слать алярмы.

**Q:** А что на счёт pip\gem\npm?

**A:** Спорно. С одной стороны - это менеджер пакетов, с другой - про его действия не сообщается "главному" менеджеру. Но если нет нужных компонентов у родителя, а они нужны позарез, то лучше хоть что-то, чем tar. Ну и если не использовать суперпользователя, то тот же питон ставится в домашний каталог не ломая текущие версии. Более того, оф. документация [НЕ рекомендует](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#installing-into-the-system-python-on-linux) ставить пакеты через pip в систему.

Comment: «проблемы с удалением» забыл...

Comment: Ну наверное как и везде, не стоит впадать в крайности. Делать пакет для крохотной утилитки тоже как-то странно. А эти вот презрительные замечания типа "*на винде работало - чем тут хуже*" говорят только о незнании предмета. В Windows то же самое - для чего-то делается серьезный инсталляционный скрипт, а где-то exe просто распаковывается из зипа.

Comment: @freim, в мою обязанность входит сопровождение +/-150 виндовых машин на которых обучаются студенты. Софт разнообразный: САПР, IDE, виртуалки. Около сотни наименований. И ты не представляешь как я уе^W устал сопровождать зоопарк инсталляторов и зоопарк способов распространения прог. В то же время на линуксе, который стоит на сотне из всего этого парка всё намного проще. Добавил репу, ключ, индексы обновил и прога установилась. А потом обновилась. И тебе не надо ломать голову какого хрена ты качнул последний netbeans и последний jdk, а через пару недель, когда всё уже задеплоено на стоню тачек..

Comment: нетбинс оказывается не запускает какие-то там окошки. И после долгого гугления оказывается, что последний неблинс не работает с последним jdk, а надо качать предпоследний. И ты потом думаешь как был грохнуть на сотне тачек новую яву и воткнуть старую. И таких историй я тебе могу рассказать просто дофигища. Так что вообще не соглашусь по поводу того, что "этож калькулятор, пусть в zip и лежит".

Comment: А, и из всего разнообразия установщиков - msi - лучшее, что я видел. Плюс есть плагин для VS, который сразу собирает установщик. Непонятно, почему гугл и адоб (не весь) пользуются, а npp - нет.

Comment: @don Rumata, я бы поверил, что в Линуксе с этим лучше, если бы мне не приходилось время от времени поднимать веб серверы, причем от разных хостеров. Несмотря на то, что я всегда выбираю один и тот же CentOS 6 x64, это обычно занятие на несколько дней. В пакетах вечно либо версия слишком старая, либо скомпилировано не с теми ключами. А когда начинаешь компилировать, то начинается такой ад, что проблемы установки под Windows выглядят просто смешно. Зоопарк в Windows может доставать морально, но там нет реальных проблем, которые в Линуксе на каждом шагу.

Comment: @freim дык 6-я ветка сама по себе старая. Цент вообще не за новизну ценится. Мы для своих задач используем centos7 и ubuntu 14-16-18.04. Каждый дистр под разные задачи. Проблемы есть везде, никто не идеален, но мне не понятно почему майки со своей монополией не сделали монополию на установщик.

В других дистрах есть нужные версии компонентов?

Comment: @freim, ну и если прям надо сделать `make && make install` - почти всегда это можно завернуть в песочницу docker\lxc.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, добавил. Спасибо.