# По какому принципу рабочий стол Mate / Caja отображает смонтированные диски?

Tags: linux, debian, caja, mate

У меня есть NTFS-диск, который прописан в fstab, чтобы он монтировался при старте с опциями `auto,user,noatime,nosuid,exec`. Монтируется он внутрь домашней папки простого пользователя. При этом у простого пользователя он отображается на рабочем столе и в списке томов в файловом менеджере слева, а у root'а нет. При этом если диск монтируется в папку `/media`, его видят все пользователи. Причём у root'а этот диск вообще не виден даже среди дисков, которые отображаются в `computer:///`. Я подозреваю, что это как-то связано с точкой монтирования, но в чём тут логика Linux?

Comment: многие дистрибутивы сознательно ухудшают ситуацию для root - обычно пользователям редко нужно запускать gui с суперправами. Но скорее всего просто диск смонтирован с правами пользователя и такие диски как раз и не видны другим. Что делать? не пользоваться рутом напрямую

Comment: Я так понимаю, за это отвечает параметр `user` в `fstabs`?

Comment: **стопицотмиллионный раз**: используйте аккаунт с идентификатором 0 (в *unix-подобных* операционных системах обычно с этим идентификатором создаётся пользователь с именем `root`) **только** для выполнения задач по администрированию системы. это относится к всем способам авторизации: login, xsession, su, sudo, kexec и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @Modus, нет, `user` просто позволяет монтировать (выполнять команду `mount`) от простого пользователя... всю информацию о блочных устройствах почти вся маломальски-современная гуйня получает от демона `udisks`, а затем самостоятельно решает, в каком виде её отображать... довольно сложно встретить человека. который бы интересовался вопросом «каков в точности данный алгоритм в таком-то DE?», тем более что достоверный ответ на вопрос проще всего будет найти в исходниках... так что если тебе действительно интересно. то предлагаю заняться именно этим...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, пришло время сделать вопрос про суперюзера. Типа как тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416

Answer (score 2):

Описания для Nautilus https://github.com/GNOME/gvfs/blob/master/monitor/udisks2/what-is-shown.txt

Чтоб диск отображался в интерфейсе нужно добавить в параметры монтирования `x-gvfs-show`.
Например у меня:

```
UUID=8b0aa814-0b3b-4bf0-8168-d67e757507a8 /mnt/bin/ auto x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

И появился значек. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По поводу рута

> In a multi-seat system, only drives assigned to the seat the session
>   is running on is shown.

Значит что будут показываться только диски привязанные к рабочему месту пользователя, DM создает отдельное рабочее место (seat) для каждого пользователя при входе.