# Как обновить docker?

Tags: linux, docker

Как правильно обновить docker с версии 1.2 до последней?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
либо скачать бинарники https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/ и заменить в /usr/bin предварительно остановив dockerd (не рекомендую, но помогает в некоторых случаях)

Comment: @TotalPusher, не, бинарники - зло: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416. Тока через пакетный менеджер, благо на бубунте всё должно взлететь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика во всех случаях и вкусах GNU/Linux  одна и та же -
добавляем официальные репозитории Docker и ставим последнюю версию:

**GNU/Linux Debian Stretch+**

```
# apt-get install apt-transport-https dirmngr ca-certificates software-properties-common
# echo 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-stretch main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys F76221572C52609D
# apt-get update
# apt-get install docker-engine
```

**GNU/Linux Ubuntu 18.0+**

```
# apt-get install apt-transport-https dirmngr ca-certificates software-properties-common
# Добавляем GPG ключи
# curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
# add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
# apt update
# apt install docker-ce
```

**GNU/Linux Fedora 28+**

```
# dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core
# source /etc/os-release
# cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
[docker-ce-stable]
name=Docker CE Stable
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/$VERSION_ID/x86_64/stable
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/gpg
EOF
# dnf -y install docker-ce
```

Доступные репозитории

```
centos/
debian/
fedora/
raspbian/
stalinux/
static/
ubuntu/
```

Можно конечно использовать NixOS, где контейнеры просто не нужны в виду нового подход  доставки пакетов.

**Ссылки**

- https://download.docker.com/linux/
- https://discourse.nixos.org/t/is-there-much-difference-between-using-nix-shell-and-docker-for-local-development/807
- https://github.com/NixOS/nixops