# Как убрать ненужные обновления в ubuntu которые уже скачаны и ожидают установку?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Например у меня установлен node js версии 8.12.

Но система предлагает установить версию 10.15 которая мне не нужна.

1. Как отключить проверку обновлений для nodejs?
2. Как убрать те обновления которые уже были загружены?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. никак. но можно зафиксировать текущую версию: `apt-mark hold имя-пакета`. 2. `apt clean`. 3. лучше приводить текстовую информацию от «штатных» программ (в данном случае — *apt*), нежели картинку от какой-то никому неизвестной графической приблуды, показывающей никому неизвестно что.

Comment: Почти в тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416