# Веб сервер для веб разработки

Tags: php, ubuntu

Поставил себе ubintu, в первый раз работаю с линуксом в графической оболочке.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то строенные локальные серверы для веб -разработки. Что бы  не ставить OpenServer ?

Comment: Xampp      https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/index.html

Comment: А вы и не поставите на него OpenServer т.к. последний создан исключительно для windows. Есть способы запустить windows программы на linux, но лучше этим не заниматься, если есть встроенные альтернативы. По поводу встроенных программ, в линуксе используются репозитории - это удаленные сервера с которых можно скачать нужные вам пакеты и самостоятельно их настроить под себя. В этом случае используется Lamp (инструкции есть в интернете), можно попробовать Xampp данный выше.

Answer (score 0):

Вот попробуйте https://laragon.org/
Virtualbox (https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416