# Как избежать опечатки при выполнении удаления

Tags: linux, bash

Иногда мне необходимо вручную обновить написанные мной программы на своем сервере. Процесс обновления выглядит следующим образом:

1. Копирую выполняемый файл на сервер командой `scp`.
2. Захожу на сервер через `ssh` в терминале.
3. Перехожу в папку с исполняемым файлом.
4. Останавливаю приложение, если необходимо.
5. Удаляю старую версию программы.
6. Копирую новую в нужную директорию.
7. Запускаю обновленное приложение.

Программу удаляю с ресурсными файлами примерно так:

```
rm -rf ./
```

Проблема в том, что однажды я опечатался, случайно добавив пробел между точкой и обратной косой чертой. Соглашусь, что лучше все это автоматизировать, но иногда есть необходимость сделать что–то подобное руками.

Подскажите, что бы вы сделали, чтобы отловить такую или подобные ошибки и не допустить выполнение нежелательного удаления?

Comment: Я предпочитаю работать с файловой системой через `mc`, что исключает ввод команд удаления как таковых

Comment: Из man rm: `--preserve-root - do not remove '/' (default)`. Если у вас не так, то пора обновить систему.

Comment: Ребята, спасибо! Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваши комментарии ответами, чтобы за них можно было проголосовать =)

Comment: Не делать это вручную, очевидно. Если всё ещё есть потребность в руках, то нужно решать эту проблему и делать так, чтобы руки не требовались

Comment: Работая рутом добавлять к `rm` флаг `-i` (можно сделать алиас, например `rmi`, в котором этот флаг будет жестко прописан) / (а вообще, работать руками чаще (и ошибки такого плана сами исчезнут))

Comment: Хинты к [абсолютно верному] комментарию @andreymal: 1) скрипт на шелле, делающий что нужно (или два, один на сервере, другой на клиенте, причём второй вызывает первого через ssh после копирования файла); 2) ансибл и иже.

Comment: Ну это же боевое крещение! Не админ тот, кто ни разу не убивал продакшн.

Comment: @avp -f отменяет -i, правда неуверен, что во всех имплиментациях.

Comment: Я прям вижу пакетирование в `deb\rpm` и\или `ansible`. Остальное - фу и отстой. Могу привести пример своих быдлоскриптов для и deb и rpm. Ничё сложного, палка-верёвка.

Comment: @0xdb, точно не во всех -- `root@avp-xubu2:/tmp# rm -rfi a
rm: descend into directory 'a'? ^C
root@avp-xubu2:/tmp# rm -rf a`

Comment: @avp Да, и у меня тоже нашёл, где спрашивает перед удалением, хотя описание в `man rm` всюду одинаково - `--force - ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt`.

Comment: @0xdb, простой эксперимент показал, что -i отменяет -f для каталогов (для файлов -f подавляет -i)

Comment: @avp Да вроде начинаю вспоминать, тут порядок важен  - `rm -rfi` будет спрашивать, `rm -irf` снесёт всё без вопроса. Попробовал и на файлах и на каталогах.

Comment: Про что я вспомнил! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416

Answer (score 14):

Утилита `rm` из более новых *coreutils* такого не допустит:

```sh
$ rm -rf /
rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on '/'
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe

$ rm -rf .
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'
```

Проверить `man rm`:

```
--preserve-root
              do not remove `/' (default)
```

В [этом топике более подробно](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410759/220332). Может самое время, запланировать обновление.

---

Чтобы максимально снизить вероятность опечатки, не делайте того, что может к ней привести. Никогда не пользуйтесь неявным указанием путей, таких как `./` или `./*`, т.е. как минимум выйти из текущего каталога `$ cd ..`.

Всегда проверяйте, что же будет удалено, хотя бы так:
`$ #rm -rf myfolder /`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> и если только ничего подозрительного нет, как например:

```
bin/                 etc/                 proc/                usr/
```

, то <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: стоит не забывать, что `rm -rf . /*` всё равно фатален...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Это только как пример для наглядности. Естественно, я никогда не набираю `./` и не хотел бы, чтобы это было понято как предложение - "делай так". Предложите, как поправить.

Comment: я про то что защита от «Патча Бармина» в GNU на практике не срабатывает для многих случаев и это ни как особо не поправишь... и, кстати, «новые» версии coreutils здесь подразумеваются новее 2006-го...

Answer (score 10):

Думал, что единственно верным ответом на вопрос будет старый добрый «think before you type», и «дважды подумай, если напечатал `rm`» — благо, обычно после пары выстрелов в ногу вырабатывается рефлекс стойкой сосредоточенности как и после команд `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`, `mkfs`, досовского `format c:` и т.п.

---

Но вот давеча сам поймал себя на том, что уже давно пользуюсь банальной «корзиной» и `mv` вместо `rm`:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/trash
mv foo/* /tmp/trash
#...
mv baz/* /tmp/trash
```

Пара замечаний:

- Способ хорошо подходит для небольших объёмов не критичных к безопасности данных, а также  предохраняет от других опечаток или ошибок.
- Каталог `/tmp` сам очищается при следующей загрузке или при отключении (если смонтирован в *tmpfs*)... Cамо собой, его  также можно удалять вручную.
- Не заставляет играть в «ответь “да” на 1000 вопросов» как `rm -i`.
- Не полностью предохраняет от ошибки класса «`rm . /*`» от root'а, но позволяет всё восстановить парой хитрых команд, если осталась root'овая оболочка...
- Любители скриптов могут обернуть это в функцию в `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  rms() {
    mkdir -p /tmp/trash
    mv -t /tmp/trash -- "$@"
  }
  ```

  ---

  Или даже расширить его до чего-то подобного:

  ```
  rms() {
    local trash dt

    trash=/tmp/trash
    mkdir -p "$trash"

    for f in "$@"; do
      if [ ! -e "$trash/$(basename "$f")" ]; then
        mv -t "$trash" -- "$f" || return
      else
        dt="$(date --iso=s)"
        if [ ! -e "$trash/$(basename "$f")-$dt" ]; then
          mv -- "$f" "$trash/$(basename "$f")-$dt" || return
        else
          mv -- "$f" "$(mktemp -u "$trash/$(basename "$f")-$dt-XXXX")" || return
        fi
      fi
    done
  }
  ```

  Помимо прочего, если файл с заданным именем в корзине уже существует, этот скриптик попробует скопировать его в файл с текущей датой, а также со случайным именем.<sup>*</sup>
- Для любителей всё усложнять также есть консольные менеджеры корзины вроде [`gio trash`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio.html#id-1.4.26.10.6.2.16.2.4), [`trash-cli`](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) и [другие](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Trash_management).

---

<sup>* Параноик скажет, что здесь возможно состояние гонки, если будут работать одновременно несколько экземпляров скрипта, но это всего лишь нудный клачёчек, написанный на коленке за 5 минут.</sup>

Comment: А если там уже есть такая папка или файл?

Comment: @Qwertiy, понятно, что ошибка будет... но всегда можно переместить в папку с другим именем... в скриптовом варианте, можно конечно добавить проверки и добавлять время удаления к имени или случайные символы, но ИМХО это уже излишнее усложнение...

Comment: @Qwertiy, всё же набросал на коленке небольшой «эвристический алгоритм»...

Comment: Ну я порсто подумал, что виндовая корзина умеет сама менеджить имена и всё остальное - вдруг и тут где-то запрятано, а нет - надо всё руками...

Answer (score 5):

если уж зашла речь про привычки, то могу порекомендовать отличную привычку: всегда указывать полный путь к файлам/каталогам.

минусы: дольше вводить команду (но далеко не всегда — см. ниже).

плюсы (благодаря истории команд оболочки):

1. в комплексе с tab-дополнением пути ещё более снижается вероятность описанной в вопросе ошибки
2. команду можно будет легче повторить вне зависимости от текущего каталога (скорректировав при необходимости аргументы)
3. в истории видно, с *какими именно* файлами/каталогами производились манипуляции (т.к. в истории команд не сохраняется значение каталога, который был текущим на момент выполнения команды, то не всегда очевидно, какие именно файлы/каталоги были затронуты командой).

Comment: +1 По моему мнению, это пока самый правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Кто про что, а я про функции:

```
remove (){
#Текущий каталог, либо каталог указанный вручную
dir=${1:-"$PWD/"}
#Запрос подтверждения
read -p "Будет удалено `du -sh $dir`, продолжить?: Y/N" -s -n1 rec
#Регист ответа
res=`sed 's/./\U&/g' <<< $rec`
#Проверяем подтверждение
if [[ x$res == xY ]]; then
#Удаляем
    rm -rf $dir
else
    echo "Удаление не производилось"
fi
}
```

Функция записана в bash_profile пользователя.
Потом из каталога вызывать `remove` без ключа - это удалить каталог в котором мы находимся
`remove /work/all/tt` удалить каталог */work/all/tt*

Это лишь пример, каждый может добавить или изменить под себя.

Answer (score 1):

Я таки уточнил некоторые детали и теперь могу точно сказать, что имеем классическую [ошибку молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/191416). Соответственно решать надо не как удалять, а как лучше запакетировать, чтобы ничего не сломать.

Есть старый, но всё ещё развивающийся проект [fpm](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), который позволяет легко (намного легче, чем писать `.spec` или шаманить с `dh-make`) упаковать папку со структурой в `deb``rpm` пакет.

Я упаковывал готовый бинарник [CoreDNS](https://github.com/coredns/coredns) в `rpm` для `CentOS 7`, потому что версии.

Мой вариант работающий внутри локалки на работе (тавтология, ага):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# WORK
# LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8

# Собираем ГОТОВЫЙ бинарник coredns в пакет для установки с помощью fpm. Он уже должен быть установлен.
# https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm
# https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html

MAIN_SERVER="10.10.10.10"
WEB_SERVER="$MAIN_SERVER"
WEB_NAME_OF_MODULE_FOR_SOFT="soft"

PACKAGE_NAME="coredns"
PACKAGE_USER="$PACKAGE_NAME"
PACKAGE_GROUP="$PACKAGE_NAME"
PACKAGE_VERSION="$(curl http://$WEB_SERVER/$WEB_NAME_OF_MODULE_FOR_SOFT/coredns/latest)"
# https://github.com/coredns/coredns/blob/master/LICENSE
PACKAGE_LICENSE="Apache License 2.0"
PACKAGE_CONFIG_DIR="/etc/coredns"
# PACKAGE_HOMEDIR="/var/lib/$PACKAGE_USER"
PACKAGE_CONFIG_FILE="Corefile"
PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE="x86_64"
PACKAGE_MAINTAINER="don Rumata"
# https://github.com/coredns/coredns
PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION="CoreDNS is a DNS server/forwarder, written in Go, that chains plugins. Each plugin performs a (DNS) function."
PACKAGE_URL="https://github.com/coredns/coredns"
PACKAGE_WORKDIR="/tmp/$PACKAGE_NAME"
PACKAGE_SCRIPT_BEFORE_INSTALL="$PACKAGE_NAME-before-install.sh"
PACKAGE_SCRIPT_AFTER_INSTALL="$PACKAGE_NAME-after-install.sh"
PACKAGE_FORMAT="rpm"

# Создаём и переходим в папку, где будет твориться магия^W сборка.
mkdir -p "$PACKAGE_WORKDIR" && cd "$PACKAGE_WORKDIR" || exit 1
# Для бинарника.
mkdir -p ./usr/bin
# Для файла настроек.
mkdir -p ./"$PACKAGE_CONFIG_DIR"
# Для юнита systemd.
mkdir -p ./usr/lib/systemd/system
# Для временных скриптов, которых пока один.
mkdir -p ./"$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"



#--- Бинарник ---#
cd ./usr/bin

wget "http://$WEB_SERVER/$WEB_NAME_OF_MODULE_FOR_SOFT/coredns/coredns_latest_linux_$(arch).tgz" || exit 1

tar -xvf coredns_latest_linux_x86_64.tgz

rm coredns_latest_linux_x86_64.tgz

cd "$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"

#----------------#


#--- Создаём скрипт, который будет создавать нам ограниченную системную учётку. ---#
cd ./"$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"

cat > "$PACKAGE_SCRIPT_BEFORE_INSTALL" << EOF
#! /bin/bash
adduser --system --shell /sbin/nologin --comment 'CoreDNS user' $PACKAGE_USER
# --home-dir $PACKAGE_HOMEDIR
groupadd $PACKAGE_GROUP
usermod -g $PACKAGE_GROUP $PACKAGE_USER
# mkdir $PACKAGE_HOMEDIR
# chown $PACKAGE_USER:$PACKAGE_GROUP $PACKAGE_HOMEDIR
# chmod 775 $PACKAGE_HOMEDIR
EOF

chmod +x "$PACKAGE_SCRIPT_BEFORE_INSTALL"

cd "$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


#--- Создаём скрипт, который будет конфигурить сервис сразу после его установки. ---#
cd ./"$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"

cat > "$PACKAGE_SCRIPT_AFTER_INSTALL" << EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
systemctl enable coredns.service
systemctl start coredns.service
EOF

chmod +x "$PACKAGE_SCRIPT_AFTER_INSTALL"

cd "$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


#--- Простейший пример конфига, который работает (проверял на 7-м Центе). Да. Начинается с ".:53". ---#

cd ./"$PACKAGE_CONFIG_DIR"

cat > "$PACKAGE_CONFIG_FILE" << EOF
.:53
{
        forward . 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 {
        }
        cache {
                success 5000
                denial 2500
                }
        log . {combined} {
                class denial error
                }
        errors
        cancel
}
EOF

cd "$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


#--- SystemD Unit ---#
cd ./usr/lib/systemd/system

wget --output-document coredns.service "http://$WEB_SERVER/$WEB_NAME_OF_MODULE_FOR_SOFT/coredns/coredns.service" || exit 1

cd "$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"

#--------------------#


#--- BUILD ---#

cd "$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"

# Внимание на "./", потому что относительные пути очень важны!
# https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.ru.html#conffiles
fpm --force \
        --name "$PACKAGE_NAME" \
        --version "$PACKAGE_VERSION" \
        --license "$PACKAGE_LICENSE" \
        --config-files ./"$PACKAGE_CONFIG_DIR"/"$PACKAGE_CONFIG_FILE" \
        --architecture "$PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE" \
        --maintainer "$PACKAGE_MAINTAINER" \
        --description "$PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION" \
        --url "$PACKAGE_URL" \
        --before-install ./"$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"/"$PACKAGE_SCRIPT_BEFORE_INSTALL" \
        --after-install ./"$PACKAGE_WORKDIR"/"$PACKAGE_SCRIPT_AFTER_INSTALL" \
        --no-depends \
        --no-auto-depends \
        --input-type dir --output-type "$PACKAGE_FORMAT" ./

#-------------#
```

Копия на [gist](https://gist.github.com/don-rumata/583910f73fcfc48d3d09cdefb7f8a013).

Дальше можно уже прикручивать [aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) и `createrepo`.