# Как осуществить предустановку нужных пакетов перед работой программы

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Например, у меня есть написанная мной программа (небольшой скрипт) на `Python`, которая использует множество пакетов, которые требуют предустановки. Для того чтобы не утруждать пользователя ненужными ему действиями, мне следует настроить предустановку перед использованием скрипта (например написать небольшой bash скрипт предустановки). Как можно предустановить пакеты перед запуском скрипта не зная пакетного менеджера пользователя? Мы знаем что Linux использует множество пакетных менеджеров, `apt`, `pacman`, `dpkg` и т.д - зависит от дистрибутива, так вот я не знаю какой дистрибутив использует пользователь скачавший мою программу. Например, в моей программе используется утилита `xsel` связанная с буфером обмена. Я бы писал в скрипт предустановки `apt install xsel`, но это не сработает для пользователей у которых стоит `Arch` или `Manjaro`. Так как осуществить предустановку не связывая ее с пакетным менеджером конкретного дистрибутива, а чтобы пакеты устанавливались у всех пользователей Linux перед запуском программы?

Comment: Может, немного не в тему, но дергать из установщика вашего `python`-пакета системный пакетный менеджер - решение не из лучших (кто отвечает за актуализвацию списка пакетов?, необходимо получение прав суперпользователя, и т.д.). В первую очередь стоит максимально перенести функционал на средства `python`, или привязки к системным библиотекам, или сторонние пакеты из `pypi` (зависимости будут устанавливаться через `pip`). Если же остаются утилиты/библиотеки, которые не заменить и к ним нет привязок, то остается таскать их исходники вместе с вашим пакетом, компилировать при установке.

Comment: _чтобы не утруждать пользователя ненужными ему действиями_ - да, и в этом нет ничего страшного. Указать явный список зависимостей - вполне хороший тон. Это даже лучше, чем под капотом по-тихому наставить без ведома пользователя ему всяких библиотек.

Comment: package dependencies вам в руки

Comment: Для этого можно Flatpak исплозовать.

Comment: @nosferatu-id давать ссылки на сайт, паразитирующий на автопереводах stack overflow - не комильфо. Оригинал - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220108/how-do-i-check-the-operating-system-in-python

Comment: Мы знаем пакетный менеджер, и называется он pip. С немаленькой вероятностью пакетов из pip/PyPI вам вполне хватит

Answer (score 1):

Мне почему-то сразу пришло проверять наличие инсталера:

```bash
arrayinst="apt-get yum pacman"
#цикл по установщикам
for checkMP in $arrayinst; do
    MP=`whereis $checkMP`
    #если пусто, переходим к следующему
    [[ -z ${MP/*:/} ]] && { continue; }
    #проходим по каталогам, запрашиваем версию типа "цифра точка цифра", если получили версию, то значит наш инсталлер
    for inst in ${MP/*:/}; do
        if [[ -n `$inst --version 2>/dev/null | grep -iP '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'` ]]; then
            echo "Установшик $inst"
            installer=$inst
            #нашли, выходим с остановкой первого цикла
            break 11
        fi
    done
    [[ $? -eq 11 ]] && break
done
[[ -z $installer ]] && { echo "Установшик не найден"; exit 1; }
[[ $checkMP == pacman ]] && key='-S' || key=install
$installer $key vim
```

думаю - это не совсем то, что нужно, но если переделать под себя и протестировать, может сгодится.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее правильный способ — создание и поддержание репозиториев с вашей программой для всех дистрибутивов, которые вы планируете поддерживать, либо пропихивание её в состав этих самых дистрибутивов. Заодно при пакетировании проверите совместимость со всеми другими программными компонентами того или иного дистрибутива. Зависимости в этом случае просто ставятся в dependencies вашего пакета.

Comment: Добавлю, что есть `fpm`, который умеет достаточно легко создавать пакеты для дистров: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025532/191416