# Как указать лицензию и иконку в deb пакете?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Я собрал свой deb пакет, программа устанавливается как надо и куда надо. Но, как мне это красиво оформить? В интернете не нашел инфы как поставить иконку или указать лицензию. Сейчас при открытии моего deb пакета в менеджере приложений иконки нет, а в бланке лицензия пишется "несвободная"

файл DEBIAN/control:

```
Package: xxx
Version: 1.0
Section: comm
Priority: important
Architecture: all
Essential: no
License: blank
Depends: xxx-dev, 365-dev, xxx
Installed-Size: 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
Origin: not
Maintainer: Hefner <HughHefner@gmail.com>
Description: not porn
Website: https://xxx.site
```

файл DEBIAN/copyright:

```
it is xxx-3.0 license:
oh, do what you want.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй собрать через `fpm`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025532/191416 минимум с лицензий там всё должно быть ок. И сравнишь потом содержимое дебок.