# Поддержка C++ в Netbeans 11

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans

Поставил в Linux MInt среду Netbeans 11.0. Раньше, в netbeans 8.2, при создании проекта был пункт C++ App. Здесь все длявеба, а поддерку C++ не вижу. Ее убрали или как-то подключать нужно отельно. Помогите разобраться как на C++ начать писать в netbeans 11.

`Linux
Пакет NetBeans C/C++ был протестирован со следующими компиляторами и средствами:

Компилятор С Sun Studio 12, gcc в Red Hat Fedora Core 3, gcc в Ubuntu 6.10 и 7.04
Компилятор C++ Sun Studio 12, g++ в Red Hat Fedora Core 3, g++ в Ubuntu 6.10 и 7.04
gdb в Red Hat Fedora Core 3, gbd в Ubuntu 6.10 и 7.04
Сборка Red Hat Fedora Core, сборка Ubuntu 6.10 и 7.04
Загрузка и установка компиляторов Sun Studio 12:

Создайте каталог для загруженного файла. При этом пользователь должен иметь права на запись в этот каталог.
Загрузите файл для платформы в каталог загрузки.
Перейдите в каталог загрузки, распакуйте и разархивируйте загруженный файл.
bzcat filename | tar xvf -
Для установки компилятора C, компилятора C++ и необходимых исправлений Solaris следуйте инструкциям в Главе 2 руководства по Sun Studio 12 Quick Installation (English, Japanese, Simplified Chinese).
Перед запуском среды IDE NetBeans добавьте путь к программному обеспечению Sun Studio в переменную PATH.`
Может ли вышенаписанное означать, что для gcc, cpp еще нет поддержки в netbeans 11?

Comment: Скорее всего плагин какой, да и сами компиляторы и SDK, наверное, отдельно должны быть предустановлены.

Comment: @0andriy компиляторы есть. Что это возможно плагин, я понямаю. Вопрос в другом. Как мне этим плагином пользоваться начать? Ибо я привык, что среду разработки запускаешь и пользуешься, без  танцев с бабном. А netbbeans в новых версиях не позволяет просто пользоваться.

Comment: А как ты поставил?

Comment: @donRumata netbeans пытался ставить через .run файл, через PPA, сейчас постевлен с помощью wget в /opt. Результат всегда одинаков. Пункта c/c++ попросту нет. Там проекты под веб только. .run файлы скачивал с оф сайта.

Comment: Какой ад. А через flatpack\snap не пробовал? Это ж не винда - тут так не всегда канает.

Comment: @donRumata При чем здесь винда? Не понял вас "Тут так не канает", вы о чем? Как не канает? через ppa, sh  и wget и в винде, уверен, не проканает. Вопрос то в чем - в том, что neybeans утсанавливается, стабильно работает, все гуд, но поддержки c++ нет. В старых версиях была такая поддержка.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416

Comment: Я бы советовал на самом деле использовать для плюсов qt-creator

Comment: @don Rumata вот я прочитал только чем плохо."программа может вести себя странно", "мутные пакеты" "могут возникнуть проблемы с удалением"...и прочее. думаю вы и сами понимаете, что это максимально размытые формулировки. Есть ли что-то такое же только с конкретикой? Просто я ставлю проги таким образом не первый раз и пока что,тьфу-тьфу-тьфу, все было норм. И вот как удалить все без проблем sudo nautilus. Перейти в корень, в поиске ввести имя проги и поиск выдаст все места где есть файлы этой проги. Выделить shift+delete. А библиотеки..старые не ставятся в замен новых, за этим уже система следит

Comment: @Sheridan вот думал про это. но разве он не для окон(виджетов, форм)?

Comment: Очень зря. Потому что дальше - ты процитировал кусок faq.

Comment: @umd он в первую очередь про плюсы и с плюсами он вполне ок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ пока не поддерживается в Apache NetBeans.
Перенос поддержки C/C++ из переданной компанией Oracle кодовой базы ожидается в одном из следующих выпусков.
https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=50465

Answer (score 2):

Меню tools/plugins, закладка settings, включить репозиторий "NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal". В закладке available plugins появится с/с++, устанавливаем, в tools/options появляется настройка тулчейна, в новых проектах появляются шаблоны проектов и примеры на с/с++