# Как на CentOS удалить библиотеку/приложение установленную из исходников посредством make install?

Tags: linux, centos, makefile

Как на CentOS удалить библиотеку/приложение установленную из исходников посредством make install?

Для примера как удалить библиотеку openssl установленную по инструкции указанной по ссылке

https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-openssl-on-centos-7/

Comment: На будущее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1
Идете в каталог с исходниками (там где делали make install) Вводите команду

```
make uninstall
```

Вариант 2. Если исходников нет либо нет цели uninstall  в Makefile

Находите каталог где установлена программа и удаляете его. Также можно посмотреть где какой файл с помощью whereis.

Comment: 1. Не сработало. 2. Нужно ли глобальные переменные исправлять?

Comment: Посмотрите Makefile возможно цель для удаления называется по другому, remove и т.п. Переменные окружения хранятся в . rc файле. Можно и их удалить.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, что значит «не сработало»? цель такая в генерируемом при конфигурации makefile — [имеется](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL#L1190)

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант make remove. 
Но можно найти через find приложение и все кишки и сделать rm -rf