# Как на Линукс распаковать весь Node.js в некую папку и настроить пути?

Tags: linux, node.js, пути

Нужно распаковать Node.js (Linux Binaries (x64)https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz) полностью в некоторую папку и использовать для проектов.

В консоли с этим есть трудности в невозможности использования npm. Не знаю как установить глобально модули в таком случае. Например, устанавливаю gulp -g и указываю папку для установки, но при использовании не работает.

Не используем пакетные управляющие и папки usr, lib. Весь node.js должен быть в одной папке. Как это можно сделать, как настроить пути для консоли?

Там же может быть и другие версии Node.js, рядом, и, в идеале, должно менять пути и переменные папки с версией нода для консоли, если бы простой командой...

Comment: НУ посмотрите как это делает nvm, например

Comment: Для активных дистрибутивов уде давно есть пакеты, добавте в вопрос вашу платформу debian, rhl, arch и тд

Comment: Поддержу @Hellseher. Ставь штатными средствами ОС. P.S. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416