# Ansible, bash, playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Такая задача:
на удаленном хосте я через Ansible запускаю установку **PCRE**. Установка, для упрощения записана в два **Bash** скрипта. Сначала запускается первый скрипт, ожидаем его окончание. Затем запускается второй скрипт и тоже оживаем его окончания.

Как написать PlayBook для Ansible, в котором корректно будет отработаны оба скрипта. Выдержаны временные интервалы, чтобы втрой не запустился пока работает первый?

Спасибо!!

Comment: Через модуль shell запустить что-то вроде `./скрипт1.sh && ./скрипт2.sh` (предварительно закачав скрипты) да и всё. Однако если вам нужно запускать скрипты через Ansible, то скорее всего вы что-то делаете неправильно

Comment: а если я через Ansible настраиваю стороний хост и там надо установить PCRE
В "./configure ...." слишком много параметров, вот я и вынес в отдельный sh все эти параметры, чтобы было удобнее

Comment: А после `./configure` идёт случаем не `make` и `make install`?

Comment: ./configure --prefix=/usr....ещё всякое развное ..... и завершение && make

 а второй файл:  make install && .......

у меня вроде как удалось их запустить следующим образом:

- name: Install PCRE 1
  command: /home/bob/PCRE/pcre_conf.sh
- name: Install PCRE 2
  command: /home/bob/PCRE/pcre_inst.sh

запуск PlayBook ошибок не выдаёт, но мне ещё нужно запустить установку Zabbix
- name: Install Zabbix
  command: /home/bob/Zabbix/zbx_install.sh

Делаю похожим образом, но возникает ошибка: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": .......

В чём может быть?

Comment: Читать до полного просвещения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416

Comment: Заббикс прекрасно ставится штатными средствами пакетного менеджера и штатными модулями ансибла.

Comment: Ну и у тебя типичная https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/191416