# Установка nodejs нужной версии

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Каким образом установить нужную версию nodejs? Если это делать через `apt-get`, то оказывается, что ставится не нужная мне версия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.0/install.sh | bash
```

Затем перезапустите терминал и сделайте например:

```
nvm install 10.16.3

nvm use 10.16
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416

Comment: Свежие версии от разрабов. -- неправда

Comment: Критические обновления безопасности ставят автоматом только трусы -- коммент сферический в вакууме. Непонятно к чему

Comment: Простите, в довесок, оказывается, что если у меня одна версия, а на проде другая, потому что так случилось до меня. То мне приходится это делать.