# как полностью доставить Intellij IDEA на Линукс?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

[По этой ссылке](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/idea/download/#section=linux) я скачала архив и в нем есть файл idea.sh. Но мне так не совсем удобно запускать из консоли. Как можно поставить IDEA как обычное приложение?

Простите за глупый вопрос! ^⎵^

Comment: Заранее простите за не менее глупый вопрос,  а что такое обычное приложение?

Comment: @0xdb простите, если я неясно выразилась, я имела в виду приложение полностью установленное в систему, то есть например как бразуер или консоль

Comment: Если у вас Ubuntu, можно поставить из snap: `snap install intellij-idea-community --classic` (или intellij-idea-ultimate)

Comment: Или через flatpack: https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community

Comment: Ну и про `idea.sh`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416