# Как поставить gulp на Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, gulp, npm

В ubuntu я переехал недавно, пытаюсь поставить на него Gulp в конце установки выдает такое уведомление:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/gulp
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/gulp
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-27T16_52_38_888Z-debug.log
```

При вводе `gulp -v`
выдает такую кракозябру:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-cli'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/gulp/bin/gulp.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:768:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/gulp/bin/gulp.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:971:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:812:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/share/nodejs/gulp/bin/gulp.js' ]
}
```

node и npm стали вроде как нормально, как минимум в отличие от галпа могу узнать версию через консоль.

Answer (score 0):

И так, вот я и решил проблему.
Сначала я полностью стер node и npm с помощю ответа в данном  [топике](https://coderoad.ru/32426601/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-nodejs-npm-%D0%B8-node-%D0%B2-Ubuntu-14-04).

Затем установил все это дело через вот [это](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAQzJkjWjp8&ab_channel=IOLEARN%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) видео.

И прилагаю список команд для установки nvm которые использовались в видео:

````
1) curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash

2) source ~/.profile  ```
````

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416. P.S. У ноды 100% есть своя репа для всех популярных дистров. Пользуйся штатными инструментами.