# Ubuntu. Удаление приложения

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, allure

Ситуация следующая. Установил allure report 2.6.0 на Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS с помощью вот такого набора команд:

```
curl -o allure-2.6.0.tgz -Ls https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.6.0/allure-2.6.0.tgz

sudo tar -zxvf allure-2.6.0.tgz -C /opt/

sudo ln -s /opt/allure-2.6.0/bin/allure /usr/bin/allure
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как теперь удалить этот allure? (ну или обновить?)

Вариант через sudo apt remove allure (или allure-2.6.0, или allure2.6.0) не работает.

Comment: Ну раз вы вручную поместили файлы в `/opt/allure-2.6.0` и `/usr/bin/allure`, значит вручную же и удалять эти файлы

Comment: Думал, может есть другой вариант.
Спасибо. Принял. Так и сделал.

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416, https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_linux