# Проблема установки docker-compose

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Проблем с самим docker нет. Устанавливаю docker-compose на ubuntu 20 которую запустил в Virtual Box.
По инструкции https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/ для Linux:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.28.5/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

похоже загружается (отображает таблицу с различной информацией по загрузке).

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

тут без вывода.
Дальше ввожу команду:

```
docker-compose --version
```

после этого отображает ошибку:

```
[4989] Error -3 from inflate: incorrect data check
[4989] Error decompressing _decimal.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Failed to write all bytes for _decimal.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
fwrite: Bad address
```

В чем может быть проблема? Как понять была ли вообще успешна установка или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Вангую, что у тебя не все зависимости установлены. Всвязи с этим рекомендую сначала прочитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416, а потом https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/, Компос в репе есть, только что проверил.