# Что делать, если альтернативы JDK указывают в разные места?

Tags: java, ubuntu

Моя ОС:

```bsh
lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (development branch)
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

Собственно, вот альтернативы:

```bsh
ls -lsa /etc/alternatives/ja*
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/jaotc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jaotc
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/jar -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/jar.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jar.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/jarsigner -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 58 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/jarsigner.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jarsigner.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 апр 11 13:01 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 апр 11 13:01 /etc/alternatives/java.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/java.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/javac.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javac.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/javadoc.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javadoc.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 дек 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/javafxpackager -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javafxpackager
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 дек 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/javafxpackager.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/javafxpackager.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 дек 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/javah -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javah
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 дек 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/javah.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/javah.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/javap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 апр  7  2019 /etc/alternatives/javap.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javap.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 дек 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/javapackager -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javapackager
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 дек 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/javapackager.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/javapackager.1.gz
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 дек 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/javaws -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/javaws
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 дек 25  2018 /etc/alternatives/javaws.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man/man1/javaws.1.gz
```

Целый зоопарк от 8 до 16.

Вопроса два:

1. Как так могло получиться? Честно, сам не заметил, когда такая фигня началась.
2. Что теперь с этим делать? Штуки типа `update-alternatives` `openjdk-16-jre-headless` не помогли.

Comment: А как ты вообще ставил яву-то?

Comment: Да много как. Я сам программист. Пишу под разные JDK. Плюс современные среды разработки сами собой всё необходимое ставят. Вот и скопилось много Яв.

Только мне непонятно, почему в альтернативах разнобой такой???

Comment: Ну вот видимо потому что ставишь руками и удаляешь тоже. Почитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я руками выкосил все альтернативы и все версии JRE и JDK, которые только нашёл. Потом явно установил последнюю JDK. Всё работает.

Знаю, что способ не очень, поэтому всё ещё жду предложений по данному вопросу.