# Windows 7 SP1. Кто знает как можно использовать ноду 14 версии на такой винде? Или виртуалки какие то нужны

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-7

Я пытался установить SP2 2012, однако там пишет что обновление не применимо к ПК. Потом, пытался установить Windows 10, там ошибки насчет драйверов. А нода 14 версии доступна только на Windows 7 SP2 и выше. Может можно использовать типо виртуалки или как это называется. Пожалуйста помогите, нужна нода 14 версии.

Comment: `Docker` в помощь

Comment: Докер ведь вроде для Windows 10? Спасибо за ответ попробую

Comment: Выше 12-й версии нода на win7 не запустится уже никогда: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/31954. Если мы говорим про прям запуск на голой ОС.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А можно как то скачать Node 14 версии на Windows 7 SP1? Без докера если можно. Типо песочница или как это называется

Comment: Ты можешь качнуть тупо архив и тупо запустить бинарник, но крайне не факт, что всё будет работать. Почитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416