# как показать программу в линуксе в установленых

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, manjaro

установил линукс и скачал архив intellij idea, распаковал, но система не показывает что ide установленa. Может я что-то не понимаю из-за отсутствия опыта в линуксе. Приходится заходить в папку программы и запускать фаил idea.sh .Можно ли как-то сделать чтоб система видела ее? Вынес ярлык файла, но способ конечно колхозный. ver. ос manjaro 21.0.7 / intellij idea Версия: 2021.1.2 Сборка: 211.7442.40

Comment: 1. https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Community 2. https://snapcraft.io/intellij-idea-community 3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416

Answer (score 1):

если Вы скачали и распаковали, то конечно линукс ни сном ни духом не знает о Вашей программе. Вынос ярлыка - вполне себе решение. Но если хочется больше, то нужно устанавливать через менеджер пакетов, тогда программа будет "установлена корректно". Но в случае Idea есть один альтернативный путь - через меню " Tools>Create Desktop Entry..." можно создать этот самый ярлык, но он будет создан в "правильном месте" и тогда приложение появится в "списке приложений".

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ мне помог исправить ситуацию. В инструкции по установке было сказано, что система инициализирует програму при первом запуске и автоматиески создаст ее в меню приложений.