# linux для пользования, а не администрирования

Tags: linux, unix, дистрибутив

Возник такой вопрос. Нужен совет.

3 месяца пользуюсь linux (ubuntu), поставил "рядом" с Windows 10. 2 "физически" разных диска на одном linux, а на втором соответственно windows.

- Установил ubuntu, скачал браузер, telegram, среду разработки, разные глобальные пакеты для разработки, по типу git, nodeJS, typescript, yarn и т.д.

При установке ubuntu зашел на форум и выполнил [настройку](https://losst.ru/nastrojka-ubuntu-20-04-posle-ustanovki).

Далее, после месяца работы, первая смерть. Проблема с драйверами видеокарты Nvidia (2 дня общения на форумах привели к единогласному решению: "сноси нах*й и ставь заново").

Второго раза хватило подольше, но в итоге я снова получил тот же ответ: "сноси нах*й и ставь заново"(проблема была другой). Всегда на форумах говорили, что мол "легче снести и заново поставить". Короче, спустя 3 месяца как то надоела вся эта история, времени на переустановку всего софта уходит достаточно.

Вопрос: "Есть ли такой дистрибутив, который ты настраиваешь, и просто работаешь. Без вот таких сюрпризов, что перезагрузил комп и все... не работает."

Можно ли вообще пользоваться linux не занимаясь половину времени администрированием данной операционки.

Если же нельзя, и linux такой и есть, то что почитать, что посмотреть, чтобы просто настроить и не париться, и даже не думать о том "запустится ли мой linux завтра". Понятное дело что можно почитать какого-нибудь Кофлера, на это куча времени 800 стр. + практика. За глубоким пониманием операционных систем я не гонюсь, просто хочется пользоваться, а не администрировать.

Comment: данный вопрос дискуссионный и скорее всего его скоро закроют.

Comment: Тем не менее. Я не уверен в чем именно заключалась Ваша проблема и с чем именно вы столкнулись. Первый Linux, который у меня реально стал полноценным рабочим инструментом а не экспериментом был OpenSuse. Он не то что не умирал, он у меня полтора года НЕ ПЕРЕГАЗРУЖАЛСЯ ни разу и работал стабильно. Очень к нему привык и после смены компа на нем винда стояла. Я долго плевался и также поставил Linux после этого ибо он работал стабильнее, но на этот раз это был Ubuntu.

Comment: С Ubuntu отдельная история. С ним у меня были неприятные моменты. Но по прошествию времени стало понятно, что эти моменты не столько касались самой Ubuntu, сколько моих экспериментов с ней. Я очень много экспериментировал со всем. Ставил разные окружения, разные рабочие столы, кучу всяких расширений (которые мало кто тестирует и за которыми мало кто следит). В общем негативные моменты касались не столько самой убунты, сколько того как я с ней работал.

Comment: Также стоит отметить что есть разные релизы всех дистрибутивов. Есть дистрибутивы с длительной поддержкой -  LTS. А есть релизы в которых вы получаете все самое свежее. Включая самые свежие баги... Если брать LTS дистрибутив и стоковое состояние без всяких украшательств - то все должно работать как часы.

Comment: ну и напоследок: кончайте общаться на форумах в которых все вам говорят: "сноси нах*й и ставь заново"... Идите как минимум на тот-же Ask Ubuntu или Super User

Comment: Я на Linux'e в общей сложности с 2013 года. За это время у меня ни разу система не доходила до состояния из которого ее нельзя было бы вернуть. На данный момент у меня Ubuntu и i3 wm.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. Испорченная кастомизацией. Пользуюсь год. Ставлю все подряд. Периодически вырубаю ноут кнопкой. Никаких проблем. Видимо у тебя просто плохая карма и тебя не любит Великий Небесный Пингвинчик.

Comment: да, есть такой linux. только это не операционная система, а программа. скачать можно здесь: https://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, видел ваши замечания в правках меток. Я учел и в след раз постараюсь что-то более подходящее в короткое описание написать)

Comment: @Nick, Удалите nouveau, хотя вырезать эту гадость бывает не просто, затем поставьте родной драйвер NVidia

Comment: Я бы посоветовал Debian с Gnome. Очень стабильная система. Гном можно напичкать расширениями на свой вкус. Ничего никогда не ломается.

Comment: >> Проблема с драйверами видеокарты Nvidia  - какая? выбрал версию в соответствии с поддержкой самой видеокарты - поставил и забыл пока видеокарта не устареет. если она устарела - не ставь драйвер нвидиа - все работает и на встроенном драйвере. 10 лет стоит у тещи линукс - нет проблем с администрированием.

Comment: Провокационный вопрос. А как именно ты ставил драйвера? Ну т.е. опиши по шагам что нажимал, чтобы дрова встали.

Comment: @don Rumata .Первый раз через оф.сайт:(https://www.nvidia.ru/Download/index.aspx?lang=ru), второй раз просто не ставил.

Comment: С сайта - не самый лучший вариант. Крайне рекомендую к прочтению: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416. По поводу установки прям оф драйверов - погугли комманду `ubuntu-drivers`, очень помогает. По поводу "переставлять долго". Настрой минимальное достаточное окружение и сохрани весь раздел с системой чере CloneZilla. Восстановление обратно займёт считанные минуты.

Comment: Сноси нах*й nvidia, ставь amd.

Comment: Тут соглашусь с @Sergey, AMD имеет открытые дрова и для AMD поэтому дров стабильных больше и с AMD будет меньше проблем, Nvidia тоже посуетилась в последнее время, но ещё не всё сделано и закончено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> после месяца работы, первая смерть. Проблема с драйверами видеокарты
> Nvidia

Чисто из практики... Работаю на разных дистрибутивах линукса более 20 лет. Винду использую только для steam - в игрушки играть, по привычке.

В начале нулёвых действительно были проблемы с видеокартами Nvidia, но очень давно уже на это не наталкивался.

Есть два варианта развития событий:

1. Вы НЕ играете в видеоигры, комп - только для работы
2. Вы ИГРАЕТЕ в игры, требующие крутой графики.

В первом варианте - просто НЕ ставьте драйвер от Nvidia и всё у Вас будет замечательно - универсальный драйвер работает весьма стабильно.

Во втором варианте драйвер ставить нужно обязательно и вот тут могут быть разные тонкости. Каждый конкретный установочный пакет драйвера расчитан на конкретную версию ядра Linux. Точно так же, как в винде. Просто версия ядра винды меняется очень редко и этот процесс всегда почти выполняется пользователем сознательно.

А вот в люнихе ядро меняется относительно часто, может даже - несколько раз в месяц и пользователь, как правило, этого даже не замечает.

И тут вылазит проблема - сменив версию ядра, надо менять и версию драйвера. А у разработчиков из Nvidia уже есть новый драйвер? А если есть - как добиться его автоматического обновления? В винде, после обновления ОС, вы сами, вручную выполняете установку нового драйвера. А вот в линухе это должны делать разработчки пакета драйвера. К сожалению, програмисты Nvidia отличаются не очень сильным вниманием к подобным "мелочам" :-(

Т.е. события (обычно) развиваются следующим образом:

1. Вы работаете нормально целый день
2. В конце, перед выключением компа, проиходит обновление ПО
3. При обновлении и меняется версия ядра
4. Утром, после включения компа, вы видите, что драйвер не загрузился.

Если порыться в логе (dmesg), то там мы наверняка увидим сообщение в духе, что не могу загрузить модуль драйвера Nvidia потому, что...

И здесь, скорее всего, есть только два варианта:

1. Снести драйвер Nvidia и работать на дефаультовом
2. Разобраться почему не идёт обновление драйвера.

По второму пункту надо анализировать логи. Как первый шаг, рекомендую выполнить команду

```
dmesg | grep nvidia
```

А дальше - видно будет...