# Как в Linux Mint Cinnamon создать ярлык для Juputer Notebook?

Tags: linux

Два вопроса есть.

1. Как в Linux Mint Cinnamon создать ярлык для Juputer Notebook? Желательно, чтобы обходиться вообще без терминала. В меню или на рабочем столе - хоть где-нибудь.
2. Если уже ярлык создать никак нельзя или Juputer Notebook был запущен через терминал. То как хотя бы терминал закрыть, чтобы Juputer Notebook продолжал работать?

Сейчас пишу в терминале "jupyter notebook" - он открывается и работает пока терминал открыт. Если терминал закрываю - Jupyter Notebook перестает работать. Причем без разницы, как его вызвать "jupyter notebook" или "jupyter notebook &".

Если нажать Ctrl + Z, после этого ввести bg и закрыть терминал - Jupyter Notebook перестает работать.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить через `nohup .... &` ([man nohup](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1p.html))

Answer (score 1):

Качем иконку:

```bsh
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyter/jupyter/master/docs/source/_static/_images/favicon.png -O /usr/share/icons/jupyter.png
```

Создаём ярлык запуска:

```
cat > $HOME/Рабочий стол/jupyter.desktop << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=jupyter-notebook
Icon=jupyter.png
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Name=Jupyter Notebook
# Name[ru]=Юпитер Ноутбук
Comment=The Jupyter Notebook is an open-source web application that allows you to create and share documents that contain live code, equations, visualizations and narrative text.
Comment[ru]=Jupyter Notebook - это веб-приложение с открытым исходным кодом, позволяющее создавать документы, содержащие живой код, уравнения, визуализации и повествовательный текст, и обмениваться ими.

EOF
```

Даём права на запуск:

```bsh
chmod +x "$HOME/Рабочий стол/jupyter.desktop"
```

Comment: don Rumata, все сделал, как вы написали. На рабочем столе появился ярлык с правильной иконкой. При запуске появляется окно "Ошибка запуска программы". И, соответственно, ничего не запускается.

Comment: Тогда уточнение, которое выходит за рамки твоего вопроса. Как ты ставил юпитер на свой минт?

Comment: Вот сейчас это уже хороший вопрос. Точно не через менеджер программ. Чем-то мне он там не понравился. Устанавливал через терминал, видимо, "pip install jupyter". Ну и этим я, скорее всего, ограничился. Проверил, что он работает. Из истории видно, что я посещал вот эту страницу https://serverspace.by/support/help/ustanovka-jupyter-notebook-na-ubuntu/ Скорее всего вот этим я и руководствовался.

Comment: Ну вот ты и сам ответил на вопрос "почему не работает". Почитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416

Comment: По-моему я не устанавливал из менеджера программ потому, что там он устанавливался, но то ли не запускался, то ли вообще не было кнопки открыть. Только не помню. И в меню ничего нового не появлялось. Я, конечно, не знаю, может это и нормально и надо было просто что-то сделать, но я решил, что он не работает и пошел искать другие варианты. Естественно я старался все установить максимально просто одной кнопкой. Но без Jupyter мне вообще никак, по-любому Windows тогда придется пользоваться, если на Linux он работать не будет.

Comment: Я, как ставивший юпитер именно на убунту пару недель назад, собирая эталонный образ для 10+ учебных классов, могу сказать, что всё отлично ставится штатным менеджером пакетов и после вызова `jupyter-notebook` - отлично запускается дефолтный бразуер на локалхосте, а `2+2*2` в вебгуе отлично отрабатывает.

Comment: Конечно, нельзя исключать, что я забыл проверить запускается ли он через терминал. Я явно на тот момент хотел ярлык. Думаете есть смысл удалить Jupyter, установленный через pip, и установить из менеджера программ? Сам то Jupyter через терминал сейчас открывается и работает.

Comment: Да, смысл есть.

Comment: Если не знаешь как поставить по-нормальному - создай ещё 1 вопрос, я напишу.

Comment: @AndreyPopov, ну чё?

Answer (score 0):

> Как в Linux Mint Cinnamon создать ярлык для Juputer Notebook?

А в чём собственно проблема?

У меня Fedora, не Cinnamon, но идея (я думаю) одна:

1. Создаю файл  */home/<Мой логин>/bin/Jupyter.sh*
2. В этот файл записываю строку *jupyter notebook* и сохраняю
3. Делаю файл исполнимым *chmod 0755 /home/<Мой логин>/bin/Jupyter.sh*
4. С помощью стандартного редактора меню (в Fedora это AppEditor) вставляю этот файл в меню

Ну, разумеется, каталог */home/<Мой логин>/bin/* надо создать заранее.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я Linux 3 дня назад установил. Еще пока не знаю, что и как. Все так сделал, значок в меню появился. Но сам Jupyter Notebook не открывается при нажатии. Есть чекбокс "Запускать в терминале" - если его выбрать, то после нажатия на пункт меню видно, что терминал на пару секунд открывается и закрывается.

Comment: @AndreyPopov  - "Jupyter Notebook не открывается при нажатии."   - Скорее всего, это означает, система пытается выполнить команду, прописанную в меню, но не может. Почти в 100% это означает, что неверно прописан путь к программе - либо в меню, либо внутри скрипта, запускаемого из меню.  Для начала попробуйте в начало скрипта вставить строку типа 'echo 'бла-бла-бла' >> ~/tmp/my.log" Пощёлкайте по меню и проверьте появление этого файла и его содержание.

Comment: Попробовал. Файл не появляется. Ни в файловой системе, ни в домашней директории. Если что эту строчку я добавлял в Jupyter.sh, который лежит в Домашней папке/bin/Jupyter.sh. Внутри редактора меню настройки такие: Название: Jupyter Notebook; Команда: /home/xeon/bin/Jupyter.sh; Комментарий: Jupyter Notebook; Запустить в терминале? - этот чекбокс по-разному ставил, одинаково не работает.

Comment: @AndreyPopov - "Файл не появляется." Это (скорее всего) означает, что либо файла */home/xeon/bin/Jupyter.sh* **нет** вообще, либо он **не** является исполнимым. Проверьте это, выполнив команду */home/xeon/bin/Jupyter.sh*  из терминала. Если сообщений об ошибке нет, то посмотрите - появился ли файл  *~/tmp/my.log* ?