# Pycharm не имеет значка запуска в Ubuntu

Tags: linux

Pycharm не имеет значка запуска в Ubuntu в левой части окошка в избранных. Постоянно запускать через терминал и терминал открыто пока работаешь.Как сделать иконку? Pycharm community.

Comment: Раз: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416, два: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322617/191416

Answer (score 3):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=PyCharm
Exec=
Icon=
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

Где `Exec` - путь к исполняемому файлу, `Icon` - путь к иконке. Остальные поля, я думаю, понятны по названию. По желанию также можно прописать комментарий к ярлыку `Comment=`, ключевые слова `Keywords=` и рабочий каталог `Path=`.

Также поля `Categories` и `Name` можете изменить на своё усмотрение, если приведённые мною категории и название не понравились.

Приведённое выше содержимое скопируйте в текстовый редактор, сохраните как `pycharm.desktop` (название ярлыка *pycharm* из соображений удобства) и закиньте по пути `/usr/share/applications`(ярлык для всех пользователей, нужен root) или `~/.local/share/applications` (ярлык для текущего). После того, как ярлык появится в менюшке приложений, можете добавить его в избранное.

Comment: И все же совершенно не понятно, какой конкретно файл с указанным текстом надо создать в ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: @avp _сохранить файл в формате .desktop_. Очевидно, что с указанным текстом

Comment: А имя файла совершенно не важно?

Comment: @avp грубо говоря, да. Конечно, лучше назвать таким же именем, как и программу, которую с помощью созданного ярлыка планируется запускать. Но это нельзя назвать жёстким и обязательным требованием, поэтому название файла зависит больше от вашего уровня ответственности, рациональности и любви к структурированию

Comment: очень всё сложно, проще сделать всё через `snap`

Comment: @em0ji если создать текстовый файл по приведённому пути с приведённым текстом и прописать путь к исполняемому файлу и иконке сложно, а заново установить пакет через `snap` легко, то я чего-то в этой жизни не понимаю