# Возможно ли встроить кастомный демон systemd в графическую оболоску ubuntu settings?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, api, systemd, dbus

Возможно ли встроить свой, запущенный из systeamd демон в графическую оболочку настроек ubuntu. Есть ли для этого api? На подобии с тем как встроен NetworkManager

Версия ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Ты хочешь кастомайзнуть "Панель управления" бубна?

Comment: @donRumata я хочу поробросить туда свой сервис, чтоб им можно было управлять из стандартных настроек убунту

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/155059 оно?

Comment: @donRumata эту штуку лет 15 не видел. но как-то встраивал туда настройки. я думаю апи сильно поменялось с тех времен

Comment: @eri, ну хз, у меня бубен+крыса+ансибл. Создаю ярлыки на рабочем столе именно с этой схемой. В 22,04 пашет отлично. Менять тип на "часть менюшки" не пробовал, но выглядит правдоподобно. Вот это вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322617/191416

Comment: так это создает ярлык в менюшке только. я вопрос понял "как добавить вкладку в gnome-control-center"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно с 14ого года gnome-control-center не поддерживает плагины. Все вкладки встроены в основной экзешник. И Нетворк менеджер там не встраивается[, а реализован заново.](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/tree/main/panels/network?ref_type=heads)

По ссылке askubuntu.com/a/155059 иконки добавляются в приложение настройки, которые сейчас называются unity-control-center - сейчас не используется.

Модификации делаются только через патчинг исходного кода. Cмотри файлы `gnome-control-center_45.0-1ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz\gnome-control-center_45.0-1ubuntu1.debian.tar\debian\patches\ubuntu\` например