# Как запустить tar.xz файл и интегрировать в систему?

Tags: linux, pycharm, tar, opensuse

Я не знаю как устанавливать **tar.xz**.В моем случае это pycharm
Система opensuse leap 15.3

Comment: tar.xz это просто архив, к архивам неприменимы слова запустить/интегрировать/устанавливать, архивы обычно распаковывают

Comment: @andreymal вы назовете меня извращенцом, но я добавил в одном проекте sfx заголовок в шебанг в тар.хз архив и запускаю через него установку и интеграцию)

Comment: 1. Рекомендую к прочтению: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416 2. У JetBrains есть установка и через `flatpak` и через `snap`. Что нравится больше - то и выбирай.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Распаковываешь архив `tar.xz` в папку `Downloads`. Затем вырезаешь папку и переносишь в необходимую тебе директорию(папку). Обычно все дополнительные программы переносят в `/opt`. Дальше открываешь `terminal` и прописываешь путь:

```
cd /opt/pycharm
```

и командой `./pycharm.sh` запускаешь `PyCharm`.

> Примечание: не забудь после распаковки переименовать папку в `pycharm`

Слушай, иногда надо просто погуглить и решить проблему, а не отмечать решение как правильное, а потом отменять решение написав, что `PyCharm` работает, но не так как тебе хочется. Я не должен за тебя решать твои проблемы. Я буду показывать решение на примере дистрибутива `Debian` но так как у тебя `OpenSuse` то действовать надо немного по другому. Вот тебе [ссылка](https://omgubuntu.ru/ustanovka-i-ispolzovaniie-snap-na-raznykh-distributivakh-linux/) прокрути вниз до твоего дистрибутива. В любом случае покажу сам принцип.

И да, это в первый и последний раз. В терминале поочередно набираешь команды:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install snapd
```

далее командой `systemctl status snapd` проверяешь статус, если `inactive (dead)` в терминал вводишь: `systemctl start snapd.service` или `service snapd start`

далее в терминале вводишь команду:

```
snap find pycharm
```

и получаешь вывод:

```
Name                  Version   Publisher   Notes    Summary
pycharm-community     2021.2.3  jetbrains✓  classic  PyCharm Community Edition
pycharm-professional  2021.2.3  jetbrains✓  classic  PyCharm Professional Edition
pycharm-educational   2021.2.3  jetbrains✓  classic  Easy and Professional Tool to Learn & Teach Programming with Python
```

Соответственно тебе надо выбрать ту версию, которая требуется. Я показываю на примере `pycharm-community`. Введи в терминале:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

Начнется процесс установки и надо немного подождать, после чего в терминале появится вывод:

```
2021-11-04T15:53:28+03:00 INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
pycharm-community 2021.2.3 from jetbrains✓ installed
```

Если `PyCharm` сразу не появился в приложениях, просто сделай перезагрузку. Теперь твоя проблема решена, запускай `PyCharm` через пуск. И да, лучше изучи что такое `snap` и `snap-пакеты` в частности. Добра тебе.

Comment: В каментах выше я оставил ссылку. Рекомендую почитать.

Comment: @donRumata очень полезная информация, спс. Просто тут человек спросил, вот я и ответил на его вопрос по простому, надеюсь ему помогло. А так да, согласен, Linux создан для прямых рук и им надо учиться пользоваться правильно.

Comment: Ну ты рекомендуешь плохую практику. Она у человека конечно же заработает, но подход закрепится как правильный и потом очень больно вылезет в других местах. Это как советовать `goto`: работать будет, но лучше не надо.

Comment: Фишка не в том, чтобы посоветовать рабочий вариант. А чтобы он ещё был архитектурно правильным.

Comment: Мне нужно что она не была как **дополнительная**.Тогда мне нужно устанвливать в **/bin**?

Comment: @lemoname так она и не будет дополнительной, все сторонние программы лучше устанавливать в директорию `/opt/`. Можешь установить и через `flatpak` или через `snap`.

Comment: Она конечно работает но запускается только  через терминал.Её нельзя запустить через пуск.И это проблема.

Comment: @lemoname я отредактировал ответ, и впредь научись гуглить. А не принимать ответ, а потом включать заднюю. Я первым своим ответом, четко решил твою проблему на счет `tar.xz` файлов. А теперь ты хочешь получить совсем другой результат... Не порядок, научись тогда нормально задавать вопросы.