# Установка драйвера Nvidia GeForce 610 в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, nvidia

Доброго времени суток всем линуксоидам на планете Земля.

У меня видео карта GeForce 610.
На сколько я понимаю Ubuntu и Mint отказались недавно от поддержки таких видео карт.

Пробовал качать с официально сайта 390 версию драйвера, каким то чудом получилось остановит X Server и войти в безграфический режим для установки драйвера, он установился но разрешение экрана 800 на 640 а мне хотелось бы как раньше это было 1920 на 1080, пробовал и Убунту и Минт, даже Арч и Манджаро.
Что делать как решить данную проблему ?
У меня есть просто графический чип установил сейчас манджаро, пробовал накатить драйвер Nvidia но без воткнутой карты в системщик он не ставится, помогите долбится 1920 на 1080

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers list` чё показывает?

Comment: Nvidia-304 384 340 intel-microcode

Comment: Ну тогда пробуй ставить 384-ю версию. Если не поможет - откатывайся вниз. А, не забудь удалить то, что поставил руками и прочти https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416