# Как установить программу для root

Tags: linux, golang, debian, root, sudo

Установил новую версию Go с помощью распаковки архива в каталог usr/local. Перед этим методом тыка пытался удалить действующую версию (1.15). В итоге удалил все папки с "go". Теперь go 19 версии работает нормально, но только из под user, а из под sudo "go" не находится. Как и в какую папку необходимо устанавливать Go, чтобы можно было использовать "go" из под sudo.

```
$ go version
go version go1.19.4 linux/amd64

$ sudo go version
sudo: go: command not found
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то "go" из под user работает, потому что я установил Go в usr/local (то есть usr/local отвечает за утилиты именно моего пользователя?), но как тогда устанавливать, чтобы утилита работала в sudo (и из user)?

Comment: Эээ... в `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Рекомендую: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416

Comment: @donRumata usr/local/ (не usr/local/bin - в итоге получилось usr/local/go!) Именно это место было указано в гайде по обновлению версии Golang. Я понял о чем Вы мне хотели сказать и прочитал Вашу мини статью. Но тогда объясните, пожалуйста, как же устанавливать новые версии программ через файловый менеджер (я пользуюсь apt), потому что я и сам уже намучался с установкой утилит вручную. А также вопрос, если Вы утверждаете, что нужно пользоваться только файловым менеджером, то как тогда устанавливать утилиты, которые не прописаны в ФМ?

Comment: @donRumata Доп. вопрос: как сделать, чтобы устанавливались новые версии программ. То есть в менеджере файловом у меня прописана версия Hahcat 6.1.1 последняя, а мне нужна версия 6.2.*. Можно как то обновить мои репозитории или что мне тогда делать с этим (помимо установки вручную hashcat)?

Comment: Я там писал про "репы от разрабов", "запакетировать", "на крайний случай - пользоваться пакетным менеджером от разрабов языка".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы использовать Go из под sudo, вам нужно установить его в одну из системных директорий, например, в `/usr/local/go`. Это указывает на то, что Go является общедоступной утилитой для всех пользователей системы.

Чтобы установить Go в системную директорию, выполните следующие шаги:

1. Скачайте архив с последней версией Go с сайта https://golang.org/dl/.
2. Распакуйте архив в нужную директорию. Например, в `/usr/local/go`:

---

```
sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go$VERSION.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz
```

Здесь `$VERSION` - это нужная вам версия Go, `$OS` - это название операционной системы (например, linux), `$ARCH` - это архитектура процессора (например, amd64).

3. Добавьте путь к инсталляции Go в переменную окружения `$PATH`. Например, отредактируйте файл `/etc/environment` и добавьте туда строку:

---

```
PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH"
```

После этого вы можете использовать `go` из командной строки в любом месте и из под `sudo`.

Обратите внимание, что в этом случае пакеты, устанавливаемые с помощью `go get`, будут устанавливаться в директорию `/usr/local/go/src` и доступны для всех пользователей системы.

Если вы хотите устанавливать Go и его пакеты только для своего пользователя, то можете устанавливать Go в директорию, доступную только для вас, например, в `$HOME/go`. В этом случае вам нужно будет добавить путь к инсталляции Go в переменную окружения `$PATH` вашего пользователя, а не в `/etc/environment`. Это можно сделать, добавив следующую строку в файл `.bashrc` вашего пользователя:

```
export PATH=$HOME/go/bin:$PATH
```

После этого вы сможете устанавливать пакеты с помощью go get в указанную директорию.

Я надеюсь, что это помогло вам решить вашу проблему. Если у вас остались вопросы, не стесняйтесь спрашивать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить в `/bin`. А вообще как выше написали, используйте пакетный менеджер.