# Установка qt на ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, bash

Захожу в папку, где находится файл и ввожу

```
sudo sh qt-unifield-linux-x64-4.5.1-online.run
```

Выходит 2 ошибки и я не могу понять и толком разобраться что они значат

```
qt-unifield-linux-x64-4.5.1-online.run: 1: ELF: not found
qt-unifield-linux-x64-4.5.1-online.run: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Название файла точно правильно

Или может посоветуйте как qt на ubuntu ставить

Answer (score 1):

Установил через

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator -y
```

Странно, что про такое толком нигде не написано. Это же неочевидно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416 )))))

Answer (score 0):

ну и зачем вы бинарный файл пытаетесь запустить как sh-скрипт ?

да и `sudo` там по идее не нужен

попробуйте так:

```
$ chmod u+x qt-unifield-linux-x64-4.5.1-online.run
$ ./qt-unifield-linux-x64-4.5.1-online.run
```

Comment: Не работает ошибка: error while loading shared libraries: libxb-xinemara.so.0 cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Comment: вроде как нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: ну значит нужно доустановить зависимости самому ручками так как вы ставите в обход пакетного менеджера. Походу вам нужен `libxcb-xinerama0`, устанавливается так `sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0`. А вам точно нужен онлайн инсталятор ? может просто установить из реп `sudo apt-get install build-essential qtcreator qt5-default` ?