# Не устанавливается dotnet в ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, выходит ошибка

Tags: c#, linux, .net, ubuntu

При скачивании через терминал `bash ./dotnet-install.sh --version latest` выходит ошибка

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dotnet_install: Error: Extraction failed
```

`gzip` и `tar` обновлял.

Comment: вручную файл скачивается? а то похоже, что нет.

Comment: я не ставил дотнет на убунту, но не нужен ли там случаем `sudo`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416