# Не выходит установить Guest Additions для Parrot OS

Tags: linux, virtualbox, parrot, parrot-os

при установке Parrot OS из .ova файла скачаного с офф. сайта возникла проблема. По бокам рабочего стола в виртуалки черные полосы решается этот установкой Guest Additions но дання функция у меня отсутствует. Вместо нее есть только "upgrade guest addition" однако при выборе данного пункта выбивается ошибка:

Running update file "/bin/sh" on guest failed: VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR_5.
Код ошибки:
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0X80BB0005)
Компонент:
GuestSessionWrap
Интерфейс:
IGuestSession {234f0627-866d-48c2-91a5-4c9d50f04928}

Скрин прилагаю ниже:
[image: скрин окна с ошибкой]

Зарание спасибо за помощь!

Comment: "Подключить образ диска" тыкайте

Comment: Но вообще можно же просто из репозиториев установить и не костылять с этой менюшкой https://parrotsec.org/docs/virtualization/virtualbox-guest-additions/

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Оказывается образ Guest Additions просто был не подключен по какой то причине. К стати ошибка не ушла но руками Guest Additions установить все же удалось

Comment: Лучше всё-таки через штатные механизмы ставить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416 . Debian же.