# Как обновить в Ubuntu консольный редактор nano до новой версии?

Tags: ubuntu, обновление, apt

Как в Ubuntu обновить `nano` до версии 7.2?

Вышла новая версия [nano](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git) но пишет, что

```
sudo apt install nano=7.2
[sudo] password for xxx:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package nano is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам как бы намекают, что нужно установить все зависимости, например чтобы установить nano 7.2 требуются пакеты:

1. libc6 (>= 2.34)
2. libncursesw6 (>= 6)
3. libtinfo6 (>= 6)

чтобы установить libc6 (>= 2.34), нужно установить:

1. libgcc-s1

чтобы установить  libgcc-s1, нужно установить:

1. gcc-12-base (= 12.2.0-14)
   ........
   и так далее по всем зависимостям и не факт, что после установки всех зависимостей этой ветки, пакеты из других веток не перестанут работать,
   по этому советуют пользоваться репозиторием для вашей  версии дистрибутива, где зависимости удовлетворяют все дерево зависимостей.
   Но если прям горит, можете по экспериментировать, предварительно сделав резервную копию системы.

Comment: Немного дополню: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907613/191416

Comment: О, оказывается есть энтузиаст: https://launchpad.net/~parkmino/+archive/ubuntu/nano