# Anaconda не ставится на Ubunta

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, anaconda

Пробую установить Анаконду, всё заканчивается в терминале.

По порядку:

1. Скачал файл с официального сайта: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.07-2-Linux-x86_64.sh
2. Сверил SHA256 скачанного файла с информацией на сайте. Всё ок.
3. Запускаю в терминале: bash Anaconda3-2023.07-2-Linux-x86_64.sh
4. Читаю лицензинное соглашение, пишу в терминале YES.
5. После нажатия Enter в терминале зацикливается:  y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что делаю не так в чем может быть проблема. Спасибо.

Comment: 1. Прочесть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416 и понять. 2. Прочесть https://www.anaconda.com/blog/rpm-and-debian-repositories-for-miniconda и понять.