Как установить ПО от JetBrains на Linux?
Как на линукс (убунту) скачать ПО от jetbrains? в связи с тем что они ушли из России. Когда пытаюсь скачать через баш, пишет ошибку, с самого сайта тоже нельзя.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Community версии без проблем можно скачать и с официального сайта.

Через snap не пробовал?

Ну если с официального сайта не позволяют скачать, то надо или воспользоваться vpn, или найти другой сайт, где скачать позволяют. наверное, первый способ проще, потому что сборников софта под линукс я что-то не видел.
https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2024.1.4.tar.gz


Кстати, вот тут предлагают
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic

PS: Не проверял, т. к. у меня винда.

Для скачивания из России доступны только community версии, проверил все предоженные способы.

@BenPuls, значит нужен vpn/прокси.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416
