Установка Google Chrome на Linux: нет прав на копирование файлов в корневую папку
Скачала браузер Google Chrome для Linux(Ubuntu).
В архиве нет установочного файла, как я поняла. Необходимо все папки что есть, просто перекинуть в корень с слиянием...
Что я делаю:

Копирую папки в буфер.
Перехожу в корневую папку, вставляю.

Но не выходит, нет прав. Хотя мой аккаунт является административным. Как выйти из текущей ситуации?


Откуда скачала? И какой конкретно линукс?

Для Ubuntu это должен быть .deb-файл который открывается установщиком, а никакой не архив.

Чтобы установить Chrome, идете на официальный сайт, жмете "Скачать", выбираете deb, после скачивания его запускаете двойным щелчком, должна открыться установка. Ничего вручную распаковывать и копировать/вставлять не нужно.

Плюсую @AlexeyTen, по поводу deb пакета. Кстати, можешь ознакомиться с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416

В том то и дело, что скачала с оф сайта. И скаченный файл открывается как архив.

Static hostname: lena-desktop        Icon name: computer       Machine ID: 8d476cc8d74f46b0914027f0a754f****          Boot ID: d8fd8bdde7bf4390b0d82425a5307**** Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS                Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-1013-raspiArchitecture: arm64

Моя операционная система

Ну попробуйте из консоли sudo dpkg -i скачанный-файл.deb

dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /home/lena/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):  архитектура пакета (amd64) не соответствует архитектуре системы (arm64) При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:  /home/lena/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Есть хорошая статья насчёт установки chrome на ubuntu, но там нужно работать через терминал(он же командная строка):
https://losst.pro/ustanovka-chrome-v-ubuntu-18-04
Не могу сказать, туда ли вы копируете файлы(себе не ставил так ничего(по идее на сайте либо в архиве должна быть полная инструкция)), но вставлять файлы куда заблагорассудится никто не даст даже администратору. В Ubuntu есть понятие root-аккаунта. У него и только у него есть доступ ко всему. У аккаунтов с правами администратора таких прав нет.
Никто не мешает зайти под root в графической оболочке(https://losst.pro/kak-zajti-pod-root-v-ubuntu), но эти танцы с бубном опасны и того не стоят. Куда проще зайти через терминал:
У админов есть доступ к команде sudo. Синтаксис:
sudo <любая другая команда>

Первый раз за сессию(в терминале) потребует ввод пароля от аккаунта(при введении пароль не будет отображаться, это нормально). Любая команда, написанная после sudo будет выполняться с root-правами. Ещё можно ввести
sudo -s

Тогда все последующие команды будут выполняться под root`ом.
Далее попросту копируете файл в нужную директорию командой cp. Её синтаксис:
cp <путь до папки> <путь, куда надо её вставить>

Подробнее про cp: https://comp-security.net/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-linux-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB/
