Как удалить символическую ссылку?
После удаления Gradle должно быть gradle --version command not found, но вместо этого
bash: /opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle: No such file or directory
Если я правильно понимаю, то это символическая ссылка. Как удалить?

FYI: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907134/191416

Проверьте явно, является ли /opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle ссылкой:
$ ls -l /opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle

Если это ссылка, то будет что то типа:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group  ... /opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle -> /path/gradle

Ссылку можно удалить как и обычный файл:
$ rm /opt/gradle/gradle-7.4.2/bin/gradle

